# Custom tags (templatetags) not loading

Tags: python, django, django-apps, templatetags

I'm trying to create a template tag so I can find out which group the current user belongs to. I have the same set up in another project but that one is working, but this one does not. This is what I have:

Project structure:

```
- root_directory
-- myproject
--- home
---- templatetags
----- __init__.py
----- custom_tags.py
---- __init__.py
---- urls.py
---- ...
--- myproject
---- settings.py
---- ...
```

**settings.py**:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    .....
    'home.templatetags',
]
```

**custom_tags.py**:

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()


@register.filter
def has_group(user, group_name):
    return user.objects.filter(group_name=group_name).
```

**home_base.html**:

```
{% extends 'navbar.html' %}

{% block content %}

    {% load custom_tags %}

{% endblock %}
```

Traceback:

```
Internal Server Error: /
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Projects\1-2-1\monthlymeeting\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py", line 1021, in find_library
    return parser.libraries[name]
KeyError: 'custom_tags'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Projects\1-2-1\monthlymeeting\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "D:\Projects\1-2-1\monthlymeeting\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "D:\Projects\1-2-1\monthlymeeting\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "D:\Projects\1-2-1\monthlymeeting\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 71, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Projects\1-2-1\monthlymeeting\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 97, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Projects\1-2-1\monthlymeeting\home\views.py", line 9, in get
    return render(request, self.template_name, {'entry': 1})
  File "D:\Projects\1-2-1\monthlymeeting\venv\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py", line 36, in render
    content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
  File "D:\Projects\1-2-1\monthlymeeting\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py", line 61, in render_to_string
    template = get_template(template_name, using=using)
  File "D:\Projects\1-2-1\monthlymeeting\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py", line 15, in get_template
    return engine.get_template(template_name)
  File "D:\Projects\1-2-1\monthlymeeting\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py", line 34, in get_template
    return Template(self.engine.get_template(template_name), self)
  File "D:\Projects\1-2-1\monthlymeeting\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\engine.py", line 143, in get_template
    template, origin = self.find_template(template_name)
  File "D:\Projects\1-2-1\monthlymeeting\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\engine.py", line 125, in find_template
    template = loader.get_template(name, skip=skip)
  File "D:\Projects\1-2-1\monthlymeeting\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\loaders\base.py", line 30, in get_template
    contents, origin, origin.template_name, self.engine,
  File "D:\Projects\1-2-1\monthlymeeting\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 156, in __init__
    self.nodelist = self.compile_nodelist()
  File "D:\Projects\1-2-1\monthlymeeting\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 194, in compile_nodelist
    return parser.parse()
  File "D:\Projects\1-2-1\monthlymeeting\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 478, in parse
    raise self.error(token, e)
  File "D:\Projects\1-2-1\monthlymeeting\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 476, in parse
    compiled_result = compile_func(self, token)
  File "D:\Projects\1-2-1\monthlymeeting\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 266, in do_extends
    nodelist = parser.parse()
  File "D:\Projects\1-2-1\monthlymeeting\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 478, in parse
    raise self.error(token, e)
  File "D:\Projects\1-2-1\monthlymeeting\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 476, in parse
    compiled_result = compile_func(self, token)
  File "D:\Projects\1-2-1\monthlymeeting\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 209, in do_block
    nodelist = parser.parse(('endblock',))
  File "D:\Projects\1-2-1\monthlymeeting\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 478, in parse
    raise self.error(token, e)
  File "D:\Projects\1-2-1\monthlymeeting\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 476, in parse
    compiled_result = compile_func(self, token)
  File "D:\Projects\1-2-1\monthlymeeting\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py", line 1078, in load
    lib = find_library(parser, name)
  File "D:\Projects\1-2-1\monthlymeeting\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py", line 1025, in find_library
    name, "\n".join(sorted(parser.libraries)),
django.template.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: 'custom_tags' is not a registered tag library. Must be one of:
admin_list
admin_modify
admin_static
admin_urls
cache
comments
i18n
l10n
log
static
staticfiles
tz
```

I have tried the following:

1. Remaking the entire project.
2. Deleting all .pyc files.
3. Tried importing it in settings.py as myproject.home.templatetags and home.templatetags.custom_tags.
4. Restarting the server, browser, PC.
5. My **init** file inside templatetags is empty
6. I deleted the templatetags folder from PyCharm, recreated it from PyCharm as a Python Package (and directory as well).
7. From manage.py shell, I tried importing using from `home.templatetags import custom_tags` and it loaded without any errors.

The same structure is working for another project that I have. I don't know what is going on. The only difference is that this project is Django 2.2.4 and the other one is 2.2.3. And this project has an extra app `django-contrib-comments`.

I have been trying to fix this and I have exhausted all the methods I could find online.

Comment: In my project I don't have `"home.templatetags"`, just `"templatetags"` in `INSTALLED_APPS`.  Have you tried that?

Comment: That just crashes the site on manage.py runserver saying `OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: '<frozen importlib._bootstrap>'`

Comment: I have updated my full directory structure in the post.

Comment: you don't have to register it in `INSTALLED_APPS` if you already register the application

Comment: I tried removing it from `INSTALLED_APPS` and it did not change anything. I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: `home.templatetags` shouldn't be in INSTALLED_APPS, but `home` must be.

Comment: Ah I made the mistake of not adding `home` in installed apps. That fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `{% load %}` your custom tags in your template.

- Remove from `INSTALLED_APPS` as that's only for apps (but your app should definitely be in there, e.g. `home`)
- add `{% load custom_tags %}` at the top of the templates using these tags.

Comment: For those who have the same problem, using my example, in the INSTALLED_APPS variable, it should be `'home'` and not `'home.templatetags'`.